# Akka Cluster: how to wait for n routees to register with a router, before routing messages

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have an Akka cluster that requires 3 nodes:

```
cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551"
      ,"akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    min-nr-of-members = 3
}
```

And then I use Cluster Singleton to start an actor, that starts a cluster aware router:

```
deployment {
        /parent/singleton/router1 {
              router = round-robin-pool
              nr-of-instances = 3
              cluster {
                enabled = on
                max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
                allow-local-routees = on
         }
}
```

This is how I initialize the singleton:

```
@Override
public void preStart()
{
    ActorRef router =
        getContext().actorOf(
            WorkerActor.props().withRouter(FromConfig.getInstance()),
            "router1");

    Runnable r = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            WorkerActor.Message message = WorkerActor.Message.addAccount(
                WorkerActor.Account.of("username_" + i,
                                       "password_" + i)
            );

            router.tell(message, ActorRef.noSender());
        }
    };

    getContext().getSystem().scheduler()
                .scheduleOnce(Duration.ZERO, r,
                              getContext().dispatcher());
}
```

When I start 3 nodes of the cluster, the singleton is created and starts sending messages to its routees, but it seems that there's only one existing at that moment, so all messages go to that one. What I want is to wait for 3 routees to be ready and then round robin messages between them.

The only way I could achieve it so far is to add a delay to `scheduleOnce` like this

```
getContext().getSystem().scheduler()
                .scheduleOnce(Duration.ofSeconds(5) , r,
                              getContext().dispatcher());
```

But that's like crossing your fingers that the 3 instances will be ready before you start sending the messages.

**So the question is what is a proper way of waiting for all `nr-of-instances` required routee instances to be ready before start sending messages to them?**

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using the `registerOnMemberUp` callback.  Below are highlights from a relevant [Akka doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html?language=java#how-to-startup-when-cluster-size-reached):

> With a configuration option you can define required number of members
>   before the leader changes member status of ‘Joining’ members to ‘Up’.:

```
  akka.cluster.min-nr-of-members = 3
```

> You can start the actors in a `registerOnMemberUp` callback, which
>   will be invoked when the current member status is changed to ‘Up’,
>   i.e. the cluster has at least the defined number of members.

```
  Cluster.get(system).registerOnMemberUp(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // e.g. Send messages to cluster members
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is kind of what I am doing. What I am starting in `onMemberUp` is a cluster singleton actor that starts the router in its `preStart()` method (the method body is in my original question). In the same `preStart()` method I am starting to send messages to the router. It seems that the underlying routees are not started in time. So that's why it's working if I add some delay before sending the messages, but I find this approach brittle. I've scanned the documentation and what seems to be the right approach is to start the routees 'by hand' and then create router around them. I will try that.

Comment: Ok, I must say I am at a loss here. I tried the Group router path. I am creating workers in cluster members immediately on start and then I am using `registerOnMemberUp` hook, to start cluster singleton that starts a router that starts sending messages to the routees. If I don't add delay between creating the router and sending messages, then all messages will go to one routee which runs on the same node as the router, if I do add delay, then the messages are round robined to all workers on all nodes.

Comment: So I don't think that starting the workers is the problem, the problem is that the router lookup of routees takes some time. One is immediately available since it's running in the same process, while the other two have some delay in registering with the router. There seem not to be a way of saying to router. Hey! Don't route any messages unless there's at least n routees. Or have a hook to execute when routee registers with a router so that I can start sending messages when 3 of them joined and not after some arbitrary delay.

Comment: S the question really is (and I updated the question to reflect this): **Akka Cluster: how to wait for n routees to register with a router, before routing messages**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I probably should read the basic documentation more carefully before diving in clustering.

The answer to this question is to send `GetRoutees` message to the router and then handle the response to check how many routees have been already added.

The `GetRoutees` is documented here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/routing.html#management-messages

> Sending akka.routing.GetRoutees to a router actor will make it send back its currently used routees in a akka.routing.Routees message.

And the implementation can look something like this:

```
@Override
public void preStart()
{
    ActorRef router =
        getContext()
            .actorOf(Props.empty().withRouter(FromConfig.getInstance()),
                     "router1");

    router.tell(GetRoutees.getInstance(), self());

}

@Override
public Receive createReceive()
{
    return
        ReceiveBuilder.create()
                      .match(Routees.class, r -> {
                          int noOfRoutees = r.getRoutees().size();
                          log().info("No of routees: {}", noOfRoutees);
                          if (noOfRoutees < 3)
                              getSender().tell(GetRoutees.getInstance(),
                                               getSelf());
                          else
                              distributeMessages(getSender());
                      })
                      .matchAny(o -> log().info(
                          "oops, I don't understand this message {}",
                          o.getClass()))
                      .build();
}
```